# Can parentheses take arbitrary identifiers as arguments? C++

Tags: c++

For example, is

```
(const int)* someInt;
```

valid code?

If so, is that statement different than

```
const int* someInt;
```

?

Comment: is this a definition or a cast? (seems like a definition).

Comment: I had in mind definitions.  At least the second statement is a definition, but you tell me about the first statement.

Comment: If nothing is in front of this code (like bla = ...) then both are definitions.

Comment: @Quonux: no, the first is a cast whether or not it's part of a larger expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put arbitrarily many parentheses around **expressions** without changing the meaning. But you cannot do the same with types. In particular, as the others have pointed out, the parenthese in your code change the meaning from a declaration to a cast.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a c style cast with any type inside, but the expression that you are trying to cast may not be able to be casted that way.

You can't have any arbitrary type on the right hand side of a cast.   You need a user defined conversion operator to perform the conversion.

Comment: Those are _variable definitions_, not casts.

Comment: Not if someInt is defined as int* for example.

Answer (score 0):

This seems for me valid, because you can have everytime a pointer to an constant value.

I don't think that between the two exists an difference.

Answer (score 0):

if `someInt` is defined as

```
int *someInt;
```

then

```
(const int)* someInt;
```

is valid. Else you will encounter error.

You deference a pointer to `int` and cast the resulting value to `const int`.
And yes, this statement without an assignment, is wasted.

```
int rtn = (const int)* someInt;
```

Comment: Note: (const int) can be other type as long as someInt is a pointer to something (not necessary int).

Comment: Also, if you original intention is to make a cast, you can correct the syntax to (const int*) someInt;

Comment: ttchong: "as long as someInt is a pointer to something".. which can be dereferenced (not `void*`) and can be cast to an int (not `struct mystruct*`)