# Parentheses and unpacking variadic template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can parentheses take arbitrary identifiers as arguments? C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246895/can-parentheses-take-arbitrary-identifiers-as-arguments-c)

My question is about using the parameter pack 'unpack' operator, `...`. The following code fragment gives a compiler error (*expected parameter pack before '...'*, on the last line), in g++ 4.7.1, and I'm wondering why.

```
template<class T> struct type_wrapper 
{ typedef T type; };

template<class...Ts> struct variadic_wrapper { };

// This compiles:
template<class...Ts> struct variadic_type_wrapper 
{ typedef variadic_wrapper<typename type_wrapper<Ts>::type...> type; };

// Parentheses screw it up:
// Error: expected parameter pack before '...'
template<class...Ts> struct variadic_type_wrapper
{ typedef variadic_wrapper<(typename type_wrapper<Ts>::type)...> type; };
```

Is the expression `(...)` hiding the underlying type's arity?
Thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: *The following code fragment gives a compiler error in g++ 4.7.1* **What** error?

Comment: You can't randomly add parentheses to the type name. (You *can* add them to the *identifier* in a declaration, but that's a different story.) In fact, parentheses indicate *function* types, and your syntax is just invalid.

Comment: @David: `// Error: expected parameter pack before '...'`

Comment: So this is a more general syntax error, i.e., not specific to variadic templates. I found a SO post related to this more general syntax issue, I will mark this as a duplicate for now.